# Switching from MVC to React. How do I write React correctly so that a table from the database is drawn on the page?

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core

Prompt when worked through MVC that created Models then controllers and returned them to Razor for display. Everything worked. Now you need to write an application in .Net Core + React. I don't understand how to pass a value to it for display.

```
public class TableController : Controller
{

    List<TableInfo> tableInfo = new List<TableInfo>();
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        using OracleConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
        using OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand($"select ID, IP from updater_srv", conn);

        conn.Open();

        using (OracleDataReader dateReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (dateReader.Read())
            {
                tableInfo.Add(new TableInfo
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToString(dateReader.GetValue(0)),
                    IP = Convert.ToString(dateReader.GetValue(1)),
                });
            }
        }
        return View(tableInfo);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TableInfo> Get()
    {
        return tableInfo;
    }
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Table extends Component {
    static displayName = Table.name;

          constructor(props) {
                super(props);
          }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('url').then(resopnse => {
            this.setState({ data: response })
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>IP</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        this.state.data.map(item => { 
                      return (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{item.ID}</td>
                            <td>{item.IP}</td>
                        </tr>
                          );
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How do I write React correctly so that a table from the database is drawn on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call your .net service from react and save data in redux store or state and then loop through each item

componentDidMount used to call api's

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('url').then(resopnse => {
      this.setState({ data: response})
    })
  }

  render() {
     return (
          <div>
           <table>
            <thead>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             this.state.data.map(item => { 
              return (
                <tr> 
                 <td>{item.id}</td>
                 <td>{item.name}</td>
                </tr>
              )
              })
           </tbody>
           </table>
          </div>

        );
    }
```

Comment: What means // your table here. How do I draw it ?

Comment: we will have to return row from loop thats why we are returning <tr> from list
and '('  parenthesis  is required to wrap html as one element

Comment: I changed everything like Yours but it still doesn't work

Comment: could you please show some code so I can understand solve it?

Comment: I fixed the top a bit. I have a controller with a method to call List from DB. How do I draw it using React

Comment: <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IP)
                </th>

Comment: I used to prescribe this